# How to get UITableViewCell reference from a UITableView disigned in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a static UITableView in Interface Builder. Each cell has right details and I initialized all of them with a value. Also, I have defined different identifiers to each cell to differ them each other.
My problem is, when I try to modify or edit this right detail of any of my cells, I cant do it because I am not able to get a valid cell's reference.
Does anyone know how to do it? I am trying to do it by this way, but every time I check the cell reference value, its null, so i cant edit the right detail...

```
NSString *identifier = @"idOfEachCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Changed!";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property for each cell in your ViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *staticCell1;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *staticCell2;
...
```

And then in IB link the static cell to the property by control-dragging from the cell to your ViewController.  Now you have full access to the cell via the property.